# GVIM Search and replace for rational numbers

Tags: vim

I have numbers in the shape of (a/b) where a and b are integers. I would like to replace them with something like rat(a,b). Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried?! These kind of simple search-and-replace questions will just invite tons of answers (already in progress after 10 minutes), since it's so easy to do (and there are so many variations)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is good at `Search and Replace`:

```
:%s/(\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\))/rat(\1,\2)/g
```

Too much backslashs! Yet another command:

```
:%s@\v\((\d+)/(\d+)\)@rat(\1,\2)@g
```

- We can use `@` to separate patterns instead of `/`.
- The very magic `\v` makes life easier.

I suggest you type `:help :s` to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
%s#\v(\d+)/(\d+)#rat(\1,\2)#g
```

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to do this is probably to create a [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) and replay it as many times as you need to.

- press on `qa` then make the search & replace stuff
- press `q` when done
- then play the macro with `@a`

If you know regex, then you can go to Search patterns http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_patterns